# understanding a c++ expression: 1[p], p a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have found online this question: (original post: https://medium.com/@vardanator/why-cs-students-must-learn-c-as-their-main-programming-language-6d3b4f8720bd)

What is output of:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int* p = arr;
int* k = p;
std::cout << (*(k + 2) + 1[p] + *(0 + arr)) << std::endl;
```

I think I understand correctly the `*(k + 2)` and the `*(0 + arr)`, but I really cannot understand how `1[p]` can be valid and what it really means.

Any simple explanation?

I guess one should not write code like this ever (or am I wrong? any case when writing something like that would be good, readable code?), but just curious.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `1[p]` is the same as `p[1]`. But yeah, don't write code like that, it confuses people and confusion in a code base is a bad thing.

Comment: `p[1]` --> `*(p + 1)` --> `*(1 + p)` -->`1[p]`

Comment: The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! Sorry for missing the solution, but googling 5[a] was not easy ^^. Any idea how to make this sort of stuff easily searcheable and / or what should I have searched for?

Comment: @Zorglub29 you can open C++ ISO and read about it, for example from here http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#1

Comment: Ok, that would have been a long shot ^^ . Thanks for your help, that was much simpler.